# ItemNotFoundException calling Remove-Item from pipeline on files outside the curent directory

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following files I'd like to remove from multiple directories.

```
PS d:\path> $files = gci -path . -Recurse -File

PS d:\path> $files
d:\path\foo.txt
d:\path\sub\bar.txt
```

I use `foreach` to call `Remove-Item`.

```
PS d:\path> $files | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_ -WhatIf }
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\path\foo.txt".
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\path\bar.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:19
+ $files | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_ -WhatIf }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\path\bar.txt:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

It would seem that when passed a recursive list of files, `Remove-Item` always tries to remove a file from the current directory.  It can remove **d:\path\foo.txt** just fine.  But it throws an error trying to remove **d:\path\bar.txt**, because there is no such file.  The file it should be deleting is located in **d:\path\sub\bar.txt**.

Note that the following code works fine, presumably because the `Get-ChildItem` is not recursive.

```
PS D:\path> del .\sub\bar.txt -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\path\sub\bar.txt".

PS D:\path> gci .\sub\bar.txt | % { del $_ -WhatIf }
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\path\sub\bar.txt".
```

Is this a bug in PowerShell, or am I not using it right?  Is there a different prescribed way to delete files recursively, subject to pipeline filtering?

Other notes:

- Including the `-WhatIf` parameter doesn't affect the issue here; it just forces `Remove-Item` to print output instead of deleting my test files.
- I can't just pass `-Recurse` to `Remove-Item` because in my actual code I'm doing non-trivial filtering on the pipeline to choose which files to delete.
- This is Powershell v4.0 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using foreach-object you can just use:

```
$files | Remove-Item  -WhatIf
```

$files returns objects of type : [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

if you run :

```
help Remove-Item -Parameter path
```

you will see that the path parameter accepts an array of strings.
`$files[0].gettype()` is not a string so some type conversion has to happen

Answer (score 1):

```
$files | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf }
```